# Extjs 6 cartesian chart yFields label right align

Tags: html, css, extjs, extjs6

[Fiddle here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/9f7&view/editor)

how do i align the yFields [Comedy, action, Thriller ] etc to the right of the chart
I have tried this

```
label : {
          'text-anchor': 'right',
           x:55                   
        }
```

and `legend{position: 'right'}`
but is not working

Answer (score 2):

You can use config `docked`

```
legend: {
     docked: 'right'
},
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1rgg&view/editor